# How do I fix wrong result produced by my mistake in the loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

my program has to fill array unique values. It's mean, that rand() assign array of random values and after that, the cycle has to control it.

I tried to use debugging with the step over and it shows me that all are ok and the program must work correctly.

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int value;
    const int size = 10;
    int array[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
        bool alreadyThere = false;
        value = rand() % 20;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (value == array[j]) {
                alreadyThere = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyThere) {
            array[i] = value;
            i++;
            cout << array[i] << " " << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Wrong is debug console. I reached -858993460 10 times in the console.

Comment: "I tried to use debugging with the step over and it shows me that all are ok and the program must work correctly." what do you mean? Either it is ok or it's not.

Comment: Debugging says that everything is ok, but it's not. " Wrong is debug console. I reached -858993460 10 times in the console." ( I forgot to add, that values have to be from 1 to 20)

Comment: I see -1 votes. Shouldn't be that harsh on newbie. The mistake that OP has made in the code is something that everyone would have made at one point.

Comment: @maxx777 -1 is not harsh. it means **1** person has found the question worthy of a downvote.

Comment: @Leeker  have you tried with seed point as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this part:

```
            array[i] = value;
            i++;
            cout << array[i] << " " << endl;
```

You do `i++;` before printing the assigned value,
so uninitialized (indeterminate) values in the new locations are printed.

It should be:

```
            array[i] = value;
            cout << array[i] << " " << endl;
            i++;
```

Also, this part

```
        value = rand() % 20;
```

will emit values from 0 to 19, not 1 to 20.

it should be

```
    value = rand() % 20 + 1;
```

to obtain values from 1 to 20.

Comment: Your advice is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should increment `i` at the end of the loop. Otherwise `array[i]` has undefined behavior when the result of `i++` is 10, because the largest allowed index is 9.

Correct code:

```
array[i] = value;
cout << array[i] << " " << endl;
i++;
```

Comment: Problem will occur not only when `i = 10`.

Comment: @MikeCAT That is because the undefined behavior changes the entire program. For example when I run it, it prints 20 values instead of 10. After you fix the code so that `array[10]` is not executed, the entire program works correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Somethings are wrong with your code and could have been found with the debugger.

- `array` is never intialized (so filled with garbage). So comparing it `value == array[j]` is wrong
- `i++;` at wrong location, should be after the std::cout

Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::srand(time(NULL));
    int value;
    const int size = 10;
    int myArray[size] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < size;) {
        bool alreadyThere = false;
        value = std::rand() % 20;

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (value == myArray[j]) {
                alreadyThere = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyThere) {
            myArray[i] = value;            
            std::cout << myArray[i] << " " << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```